# How "==" works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I found `==` is little confusing for newbies, So I want someone to explain how it works.

For example -

```
new String("a") == "a" and "a" == new String("a") are both true.
new String("a") == new String("a") is false.
```

Why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: It's an equality operator... What's the question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`==` is called comparison/equality operator, it compares 2 values, but not their data types so for example

`1 == '1'` will return `true`, for stricter comparison, use `===` which will compare the data types too so `1 === '1'` will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

`==` is a comparison operator that means "equal to" but does not take variable typing into account.

`===` is a stricter comparison operator that means "equal to and same type".

So if you have a `string` called `numberStr` with a value of `2` and an `integer` called `numberInt` with a value of `2`, they will evaluate as follows:

```
numberStr == numberInt  // evaluates to true
numberStr === numberInt // evaluates to false because types are different
```